# Tensorflow Tf.tf.squared_difference is showing a value error

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras Input layer, then I add an embedding layer. Whenever I try to execute the following code

```
vector = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(user, book), 1, name="pos_distances")
```

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer prediction: expected
>   min_ndim=2, found ndim=1

Here is the shape of the input tensors

```
user :   Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32) 

book :   Tensor("Shape_1:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

It is giving me this error

```
vector = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(user, book), 1, name="pos_distances")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tensors don't have the `axis=1`, over which you are trying to perform the reduction ( second argument of the `tf.reduce_sum()`). It should rather be

```py
sqrt_diff = tf.squared_difference(user, book)
vector = tf.reduce_sum(sqrt_diff, 0, name="pos_distances")
```

Comment: So the result will be different then. Because, as far as I know x = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
tf.reduce_sum(x)  # 6
tf.reduce_sum(x, 0)  # [2, 2, 2]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1)  # [3, 3]