# Tensorflow Tf.tf.squared_difference is showing a value error with dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

Whenever I try to multiply two tensors and then feed them as an input to a dense layer, it is working perfectly. But, when I try to calculate the squared difference between them, it's showing me an error.

```
# working well
out= multiply([user, book])    

result = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializers.lecun_normal(),
                   name='prediction')(out)
# error
out= tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(user, book),1)

result = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializers.lecun_normal(),
                   name='prediction')(out)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer prediction: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1 error
```

Comment: You asked a very similar question two days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520942/tensorflow-tf-tf-squared-difference-is-showing-a-value-error Please don't post questions more than once, you can always edit your question to add new information

Comment: Yeah bro, But the solution wasn't there. This post helped me. My issue is resolved now

Comment: Doesn't matter, as I said, don't repost questions. Improve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to pass `keepdims=True` argument to `reduce_sum` function in order to keep the dimensions with length 1 (otherwise, the shape of `out` would be `(batch_size)`, whereas the `Dense` layer expects `(batch_size, N)`):

```
out= tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(user, book), axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

**Update:** The input of Keras layers must be the output of other Keras layers. Therefore, if you want to use TensorFlow operations, you need to wrap them inside a `Lambda` layer in Keras. For example:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda

out = Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(x[0], x[1]), axis=1, keepdims=True))([user, book])
```

Comment: I did, however, it is still showing me an error. But, this time the error is a bit different. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Comment: @tauhidullah You also need to put this operation inside a `Lambda` layer. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851738/2099607).

Comment: I really appreciate your kind response and help. Thank you so much bro